Prove $\sqrt{\frac{a+bc}{b+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{b+ac}{a+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{c+ba}{b+a}}\ge 3.$
Let $a,b,c$ be nonnegative real numbers such that $a+b+c+abc=4$, prove that
$$\sqrt{\frac{a+bc}{b+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{b+ac}{a+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{c+ba}{b+a}}\ge 3.$$
I've seen it here (#10). I tried Holder but I cannot find a suitable yield
$$\left(\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a+bc}{b+c}} \right)^2 \sum_{cyc} (b+c)(a+bc)^2A^3\geq \left(\sum_{cyc} (a+bc)A\right)^3.$$
because it has 2 equality cases: $a=b=c$ and $(0,2,2)$. I also tried AM GM or Cauchy Schwarz but I haven't had anything useful. Can anyone help me with this problem? Thank you.
Edit: My friend said that River Li's lemma cannot be applied for this kind of this problem, and I don't know why.
RL's lemma. For $a,b,c$ be nonnegative real numbers such that
$$a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2+\frac{33}{16}a^2b^2c^2 \ge \frac{81}{16}.$$
then $a+b+c\ge 3$.

well if the famed argady hasn't found a solution, this must indeed be hard. Also, how did you verify this inequality is indeed true ?

@dezdichado I have no idea how to verify it. But aqardy tried it, so I think it's true indeed.

Some thoughts.
By Holder, we have
$$\left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\sqrt{\frac{a+bc}{b+c}}\right)^2\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (b+c)(a+bc)^2(2ab + bc + 2ca)^3$$
$$\ge \left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (a+bc)(2ab + bc + 2ca)\right)^3.$$
It suffices to prove that
$$\left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (a+bc)(2ab + bc + 2ca)\right)^3 \ge 9 \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (b+c)(a+bc)^2(2ab + bc + 2ca)^3.$$
It is verified by Mathematica - a Computer Algebra System (CAS).

Very nice Holder. Thank you.

@30AnhTi711 You are welcome. Hope to see nice proofs.
